# Why wont variable line1 and line2 write to the file 'USERDATA.py'?

Tags: python-3.x

Im sorry if this is the wrong area to post this. It has been a while since I have touched python (code in general) so the code i have presented is most likely horrendous but it wont write variable line1 and line2 to the USERDATA.py file and i cant figure out why, any help would be appreciated. Cheers

```
    #import
import os

#
runstartText = 'Start success'
print(runstartText)

#setting values
file1 = './data'
file2 = './data/userpass'
file3 = './data/userpass/access.py'
newUserTEXT1 = 'Please input a valid email, username and password'

#checking/creating directorys
if not os.path.exists(file1):
    os.makedirs(file1)
    print('Created', file1)

if not os.path.exists(file2):
    os.makedirs(file2)
    print('Created', file2)


#def
def newUser():
    print(newUserTEXT1)
    username = input('Enter New System Username: ')
    password = input('Enter New System Password: ')
    passwordConfirm = input('Re-Enter New System Password: ')
    if password == passwordConfirm:
        print('Username and Password Stored')
        line1 = 'username = ', username
        line2 = 'username = ', password
        apples = 1
        if apples == 1:
            userdatafile = open('USERDATA.py', 'w+')
            userdatafile.writelines([line1, line2,])
            userdatafile.close()


        #-> store data
        #-> to login
    if password != passwordConfirm:
        print('ERROR: Passwords do not match, please retry')
        #-> restart newUser string

def login():
    from USERDATA import username, password
    print('Please Enter Username and Password:')
    usernameTEMP = input('Username: ')
    if usernameTEMP == username:
        passwordTEMP = input('Password: ')
        if passwordTEMP == password:
            print('Successful Login!')
            # -> to login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you never actually call `newUser()`.  I added a call and get the error:

`line 37, in newUser
    userdatafile.writelines([line1, line2,])
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple`

So we should replace the tuple inside: `userdatafile.writelines([line1, line2,])` with a string `userdatafile.writelines("".join(line1).join(line2))`

and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Hoog already noted, foremost problem is you are not calling the `newUser` function. Always show all relevant code in questions and strip unnecessary detail.

The next biggest problem I see in your code, is that you are not building strings to write to the file. I guess the definitions of `line1` and `line2` should read like this:

```
line1 = 'username = ' + username + '\n'
line2 = 'password = ' + password + '\n'
```

One important warning: I hope you do this only as an exercise. This is not even near a correct way to handle account data.